How to configure CORS for Vert.x deployed in Google Cloud App Engine
enter image description hereI'm trying to deploy my Vert.x backend to GCloud on App Engine and it's currently deployed but inaccessible.
I'm going to get straight to it. My backend has 2 files, SamlVerticle.java which is my deployed verticle and SamlHandlers.java which contains all the handlers for any routes I need.
SamlVerticle.java
  public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("SAML Verticle Started");
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    // CORS Handler
    // router.route().handler(CorsHandler.create(SamlConstants.FRONTEND_URL_PROD));
    router.route().handler(SamlHandlers.handlerCheckCorsHeaders());
    router.route().method(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).handler(SamlHandlers.handlerOptionsMethod());

    // BodyHandler is used to parse the request body into a RequestBody object.
    router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

    router.get("/").handler(SamlHandlers.getBaseHandler());
    
    // ...other handlers and server creation on port 8080

  }

OR
    router
        .route()
        .handler(
            CorsHandler.create("*")
                .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method")
                .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods")
                .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers")
                .allowedHeader("Content-Type"));

SamlHandlers.java
  public static Handler<RoutingContext> handlerCheckCorsHeaders() {
    return context -> {
      final HttpServerResponse response = context.response();
      final String origin = context.request().getHeader("Origin");

      if (origin != null && origin.equals(SamlConstants.FRONTEND_URL_PROD)) {
        response.putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        response.putHeader("Vary", "Origin");
      }
      context.next();
    };
  }

  public static Handler<RoutingContext> getBaseHandler() {
    return context -> {
      context.response().end("Simple Response");
    };
  }

  public static Handler<RoutingContext> handlerOptionsMethod() {
    return context -> {
      final HttpServerResponse response = context.response();
      final String origin = context.request().getHeader("Origin");

      if (origin != null && origin.equals(SamlConstants.FRONTEND_URL_PROD)) {
        response.putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        response.putHeader(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, HEAD, DELETE");

        response.putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
      } else {
        // Consider returning a more informative error message
        response.setStatusCode(403).end("Forbidden");
      }
      // Your available methods might vary!
      context.end("OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, HEAD, DELETE");
    };
  }

  // ...other handlers

All of this worked locally without any preflight request implementation. However, once deployed I'm having CORS errors left and right and I can't seem to figure it out.
Here's my console log from the frontend (also hosted on appengine) after I send the request:
Access to fetch at /some/api from origin  has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
I have tried various different configurations of trying to set the headers but it just doesn't seem to work. Maybe it's some appengine specific setting that I'm missing out on.
In my networks tab (frontend)
sometimes I get errors like this:
Single error
Or sometimes I get an error like this: based on what config I'm running
Other times it has two request errors:

an OPTION preflight request that gets a 503 error
and another consume request I think, that also failed because the preflight failed.


What is the value of SamlConstants.FRONTEND_URL_PROD? And did you mean a 403 error rather than a 503 error?

@jub0bs I can't reveal the value of the URL but it's an https.com url that appengine gave me for my hosted app. I've double checked it many times and I also know that importing variables using SamlConstants.VAR_NAME works. And it is a 503 error, I'm updating my original post with a screenshot.

Make sure the value of SamlConstants.FRONTEND_URL_PROD doesn't contain a path. As for the 503 response, I'm not sure what's causing it, but resolving that issue would likely also resolve whatever CORS issue you're facing.
